# Extract elements of lists in an RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

### What I want to achieve

I'm working with Spark and Scala. I have two Pair RDDs.

```
rdd1 : RDD[(String, List[String])]
rdd2 : RDD[(String, List[String])]
```

Both RDDs are joined on their first value.

```
val joinedRdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

So the resulting RDD is of type `RDD[(String, (List[String], List[String]))]`. I want to map this RDD and extract the elements of both lists, so that the resulting RDD contains just these elements of the two lists.

---

### Example

```
rdd1 (id, List(a, b))
rdd2 (id, List(d, e, f))
wantedResult (a, b, d, e, f)
```

---

### Naive approach

My naive approach would be to adress each element directly with `(i)`, like below:

```
val rdd = rdd1.join(rdd2)
    .map({ case (id, lists) => 
        (lists._1(0), lists._1(1), lists._2(0), lists._2(2), lists._2(3)) })

/* results in RDD[(String, String, String, String, String)] */
```

Is there a way to get the elements of each list, without adressing each individually? Something like "`lists._1.extractAll`". Is there a way to use `flatMap` to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you sure you want to extract the elements? Your question seems to be asking how to flatten the list of lists into one value for a given ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the two lists with the `++` operator:

```
val res: RDD[List[String]] = rdd1.join(rdd2)
  .map { case (_, (list1, list2)) => list1 ++ list2 }
```

Probably a better approach that would avoid to carry `List[String]` around that may be very big would be to explode the RDD into smaller (key value) pairs, concatenate them and then do a `groupByKey`:

```
val flatten1: RDD[(String, String)] = rdd1.flatMapValues(identity)
val flatten2: RDD[(String, String)] = rdd2.flatMapValues(identity)
val res: RDD[Iterable[String]] = (flatten1 ++ flatten2).groupByKey.values
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution with the `++` operator. I added `mkString` to get an RDD[String] (`res.map { case (_, (list1, list2)) => (list1 ++ list2).mkString(",") }`). I think you mean `(flatten1 ++ flatten2)` instead of `(rdd1 ++ rdd2)` in the second part of your post?

Comment: I've tried your suggestion to avoid carrying `List[String]`, but I don't see how this is going to achieve the same result, since I need to join my two RDDs on the `id` value.